# Селекторы css: Выбор по два через два

Tags: css3, css

Есть таблица с кучей таких строк:

> ```
> <tr>
> <td rowspan="2" width="1"><img src="path"></td>
> <td><a href="#" class="uname">Вовчик</a></td>
> <td rowspan="2">1</td>
> <td rowspan="2">2</td>
> <td rowspan="2">3</td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
> <td>4</td>
> </tr>
> ```

Необходимо поставить фон строкам: 1и2, 5и6, 9и10 (по 2 через 2) - возможно ли это как то сделать с помощью селекторов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
td:nth-child(1+4n),td:nth-child(2+4n){}
```

Comment: Посмотреть можно здесь: http://jsfiddle.net/Eu3dz/

Comment: Спасибо, Павел!

Answer (score 0):

да, конечно можно

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Извините, не сразу понял вопрос, эти селекторы работают через 1, то есть четные и нечетные...